# Intuitive explanation for one of the conditions in Kolmogorov's Predator-Prey theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, intuition

I'm reading Nowak's “Evolutionary dynamics”. In page 67 he introduces Kolmogorov's Prey-predator equation, in the form
$$\dot{x}=xF\left(x,y\right)$$
$$\dot{y}=yG\left(x,y\right)$$

where $F$ and $G$ are $C^{1}$ functions. The variable $x$ is interpreted as the amount of prey while $y$ represents the amount of predators. A theorem by Kolmogorov is then stated - That this system has a stable equilibrium or a limit cycle if 8 conditions for $F$ and $G$ are met. One of these conditions is

$$x\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}<0$$

And Nowak's interpretation of this condition is that “For any given ratio of the two species, the rate of increase of prey is a decreasing function of population size”.

Can someone explain why this is a valid interpretation of the condition?

Comment: The condition $x\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}<0$ is the same as $(x,y)\cdot \nabla F<0.$